# How to link a static library to another

Tags: c, static-libraries, .a

I have a problem with my static libraries. I got one for the use of multimedia elements and
another for C general use (linked list...).  I want them to be separated to not bloat my program.

Try as I might to use functions from the second library in the first I keep getting the pesky undefined references. I can't find the answer on Google or in the gcc documentation so I came here to find the answer I seek.

How do I link together two .a files?
Can gcc even do this ?

linking the .c file of an element of lib1

```bash
gcc -g3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I src/inc -I src/lib/*/src/inc -L src/lib -locl -o obj/menu/button.o -c src/menu/button.c
```

creating lib1

```bash
ar rcso ../libocml.a  obj/sound/sound.o obj/sys/view.o obj/sys/window.o obj/sys/thread.o obj/sys/clock.o obj/menu/text.o obj/menu/button.o
```

Compiling of the binary

```bash
gcc -g3 -Wall -Wextra -I src/inc -I src/lib/*/src/inc -I src/lib/*/src/lib/*/src/inc -L src/lib -o bin/runner.exe  obj/main.o -locml -lcsfml-graphics -lcsfml-window -lcsfml-audio -lcsfml-system
```

Unedited error

```bash
gcc -g3 -Wall -Wextra -I src/inc -I src/lib/*/src/inc -I src/lib/*/src/lib/*/src/inc -L src/lib -o bin/runner.exe  obj/main.o -locml -lcsfml-graphics -lcsfml-window -lcsfml-audio -lcsfml-system  
/usr/bin/ld : src/lib/libocml.a(sound.o) : dans la fonction « setMusic » :
/home/ornsolot/Bureau/runner/src/lib/ocml/src/sound/sound.c:69 : référence indéfinie vers « setStr »
/usr/bin/ld : src/lib/libocml.a(sound.o) : dans la fonction « unsetMusic » :
/home/ornsolot/Bureau/runner/src/lib/ocml/src/sound/sound.c:82 : référence indéfinie vers « unsetStr »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:86 : runner] Erreur 1
```

the issue is that setMusic and unsetMusic in music.c in lib ocml need setStr and unsetStr in str.c in lib ocl.

Source Tree
[Source tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tZyp.png)

How to reproduce

you need the csfml library for compile it, `sudo apt-get install libcsfml-dev`
create all file at the same place where you fill use the following command.

ocml.h

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.h>
#include <SFML/Audio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MALLOCSTR(length) (malloc(sizeof(char) * length))
typedef struct osString_s {
    char  *data;
    size_t length;
} String_t;
String_t *setStr(char *data);
void unsetStr(String_t *string);
typedef struct ocmlMusic_s {
    sfMusic  *core;
    String_t *name;
} Music_t;
Music_t *setMusic(char *path, sfBool loop);
void unsetMusic(Music_t *music);
```

str.c

```c
#include "ocml.h"
static size_t strLen(char *string)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    
    if (string)
        while (string[len] != '\0')
            len++;
    return (len);
}
String_t *setStr(char *data)
{
    size_t len = strLen(data);
    String_t *str = len > 0 ? malloc(sizeof(String_t)) : NULL;

    if (str) {
        str->data = MALLOCSTR(len);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len ; i++)
            str->data[i] = data[i];
        str->length = len;
    }
    return (str);
}
void unsetStr(String_t *string)
{
    if (string) {
        if (string->data)
            free(string->data);
        free(string);
    }
}
```

```bash
gcc -g3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I . -o str.o -c str.c
ar rcso libocml.a  str.o
```

music.c

```c
#include "ocml.h"

Music_t *setMusic(char *path, sfBool loop)
{
    Music_t *music = (path) ? malloc(sizeof(Music_t)) : NULL;

    if (music) {
        music->core = sfMusic_createFromFile(path);
        sfMusic_setLoop(music->core, loop);
        music->name = setStr(path);
    }
    return (music);
}
void unsetMusic(Music_t *music)
{
    if (music) {
        sfMusic_destroy(music->core);
        unsetStr(music->name);
        free(music);
    }
}
```

```bash
gcc -g3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I . -L . -locl -o music.o -c music.c
ar rcso libocml.a  music.o libocl.a
```

main.c

```
#include "ocml.h"
int main()
{
    Music_t*loop = setMusic("path/to/file.ogg", sfTrue);
    unsetMusic(loop);
}
```

gcc -g3 -Wall -Wextra -I . -L . -o a.out  main.o -locml -lcsfml-graphics -lcsfml-window -lcsfml-audio -lcsfml-system

Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Comment: Please show the exact, complete and unedited error message you are getting.

Comment: You don't link .a files together.  They are an archive which you can manipulate with `ar`.  It looks option `a` or `b` can be used to add files.

Comment: It looks like you're putting the `libocml.a` in a different folder than you include with a -L though it isn't clear.

Comment: I have edited the description.

Comment: You might add which source file and library is supposed to provide the 2 mentioned functions that are not found.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ar rcso libocml.a  music.o libocl.a
```

This command creates an archive with two members, `music.o` and `libocl.a`. The second member is completely useless for linking. Only members that are object files are useful. When searching `libocml.a`, the linker will only see `music.o`. It will not search `libocl.a` and will not see any objects that are members of that archive.

If you want an archive that has all the contents of `libocl.a` plus `music.o`, you can do it:

```
cp libocl.a libocml.a
ar rs libocml.a music.o
```

I fail to see the point though. If libocl.a is your library, just skip it and build libocml.a directly out of objects. If it is a third party library, don't modify it. Build your own libraries with your own code.

Comment: The point is to compile multiple binary but with the functions they need without the bloat.
Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you link against a static library, only objects that are actually used are included in the final executable. There is no bloat regardless of how many unused objects are archived in the library.

Answer (score 2):

> Compiling lib1
>
> `ar rcso …`

`ar` is not a compilation command. It is a library manipulation command. The command form you used puts object files into the library. This is simply putting multiple files into one container file. It is not compilation or linking.

> Compiling of the binary
>
> `gcc … obj/main.o -locml -lcsfml-graphics -lcsfml-window -lcsfml-audio -lcsfml-system`

That form of the `gcc` command does not compile. It links, by executing the linker program (typically called `ld`).

The linker processes files in the order they are listed on the command line. When it processes each object module, it makes a note of symbols needed by that object module. When it processes each library file, it takes from that library only the routines that define symbols that are currently known to be needed.

Because of that, any library that provides symbols needed by another library (or by an isolated object module) must be listed on the command line after the library that needs it. You have not told us which of those file names are which library or define which symbols, so we cannot check the order is correct.

However, since `ocml` is the first library listed in your command line (albeit after the `main` object module), it appears none of your libraries define `setMusic` or `unsetMusic`. If one of your libraries is expected to define those, you may have some other problem such as one library being written in C and another being written in C++ so that one uses the decorated linker symbol names of C++ and the other does not. There is insufficient information in the question for a complete diagnosis.

Comment: Compilation are made via makefile, each lib has it's own makefile, each makefile link sources files in on library, lib1 compile lib2 before linking it's file.

setMusic/unsetMusic in lib1 need setStr/unsetStr in lib2.

Comment: I use compiling in stead of linking my bad i will edit the main post.